# How to create an html server in Vert.x/groovy?

Tags: groovy, vert.x

I want to create a Vert.x server to which I can connect using firefox. When a user requests a page, the server should be able to fetch the html and return it to the user.
What is the best approach to get the HTML data and return it to the user? Should I return the html as string or as a file?. It should also serve any embedded js/css/images.

Answer (score 1):

There is already an example in vertx, please check [this link](https://github.com/vert-x/vertx-examples/tree/master/src/modules/groovy/webapp/mods). In this example, a module named mod-web-server was used.